# Windows authentication in IIS 8.5 without pop up appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-8

I'm pretty new to Net Core and IIS management. My question is: is it possible to make a windows authentification without asking the user to type their credentials in the classic pop-up provided by IIS? For example, if an user in my company network logs in in their windows computer, then the pop up doesn't appear as their credentials were already identified before. For the moment I use `User.Identity.Name` to get the current user name after the user enters their credentials through IIS. Or is there a way to change the pop up apperance to make it more user friendly?

Comment: "Or is there a way to change the pop up apperance to make it more user friendly?" - no, because Windows Authentication (NTLM, Kerberos)  must be performed *before* the document is requested.

Comment: You *can* use Active Directory as the "backend" for a Forms-based authentication scheme, but that's not "real" Windows Authentication because it isn't using the user's NTLM/Kerberos ticket.

Comment: "Windows Authentication" is dying anyway because it doesn't work over the Internet (as the Kerberos KDS is not contactable outside of a LAN for reasons I still don't fully understand). The "modern" way forward is OIDC (e.g. "Azure AD") - which has a very, very steep learning curve. Good luck!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/prompt-for-username-and-password Purely a browser side behavior.

Comment: Windows authentification sounds very limited. It's a shame that my boss asks me to do it like that. Thank you for your time and reply. Is there some article or course I can look for to get me going with OIDC that you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the browser to not pop up, it is better to use an Active Directory account.

1. Open the 'Customize' menu (upper right corner) in Chrome and select
   Settings.
2. In the 'System' section, click on 'Open proxy settings.'
3. Click the 'Security tab > Trusted Sites icon', then click the
   'Sites' button and enter the URL of your Trusted Site, then click
   Add.
4. Click 'Close' to close the Trusted Sites window.
5. Click on 'Security tab > Local intranet' then the 'Custom level...'
   button.
6. Scroll to the bottom and select the 'Automatic logon with current
   user name and password'

   option. It's under the 'Authentication > Logon' section.
7. Click OK to save the changes.
8. Do steps 5 and 6 for the 'Trusted Sites' zone also.
9. Click OK to save all the changes and close the Properties window.

Add your site into the Trusted Sites zone in Internet Properties and set "Automatic logon with current user name and password" in Local Intranet and Trusted Sites zones.